# how to use batchRunReports?

Tags: google-analytics

fetch `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/${property}:batchRunReports`

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "dateRanges": [
        {
          "startDate": "2023-11-08",
          "endDate": "2023-11-08"
        }
      ],
      "dimensions": [
        {
          "name": "country"
        }
      ],
      "metrics": [
        {
          "name": "totalUsers"
        }
      ],
      "orderBys": [
        {
          "desc": true,
          "metric": {
            "metricName": "totalUsers"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

works ok

```
{
  "reports": [
    {
      "dimensionHeaders": [
        {
          "name": "country"
        }
      ],
      "metricHeaders": [
        {
          "name": "totalUsers",
          "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
        }
      ],
      "rows": [
        {
          "dimensionValues": [
            {
              "value": "United States"
            }
          ],
          "metricValues": [
            {
              "value": "1651"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rowCount": 1,
      "metadata": {
        "currencyCode": "USD",
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
      },
      "kind": "analyticsData#runReport"
    }
  ],
  "kind": "analyticsData#batchRunReports"
}
```

How can we get one batch query for some different properties at the same time?